# Nginx removes file from POST request

Tags: node.js, docker, rest, nginx, post

I'm having application with react.js and react-native front-ends and node.js backend. I'm trying to dockerize it and put Nginx docker in between. Basic configuration works fine for most of the API calls, except those having files attached in post request.

On the client side I'm appending image as 'file' to FormData and sending it as post request, e.g.:

```
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', image);
        formData.append('orderType', 'newrx');
        formData.append('instructions', instructionsText);
        formData.append('pickupDate', pickupDate);

...
        const headers = {
          headers: {
            'content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
          }
        }
        return Axios.post(`/api/v1/orders/user/${userId}/new`, formData, headers);
```

On the backend side I'm using multer:

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({storage: storage,
limits: {fieldSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024}});

router.route('/api/v1/orders/user/:userId/new')
    .post(upload.single('file'), orderCtrl.createNewRx)

 ...
 const file = req.file;
    if (file) {
     ...
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({error: 'File is mandatory'});

    }
```

Initially, I was getting errors related to nginx buffer and body size which I was able to resolve by adding

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
client_body_buffer_size 200M;
```

but now, I'm not having any error from nginx. Requests are going through, but on the backend side there is no file attached to request.

My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /api {
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    client_body_buffer_size 200M;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It turned out that this is not related to nginx or multer, but to ImagePicker which on iOS has an issue to properly extract fileName (https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1271).

Comment: Are other fields accessible from backend side (orderType, instructions, pickupDate)?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that file gets attached to req.body, which is weird and seems to be done by nginx. I'm testing this right now with 2 mobile devices Android and iPhone. With Android it comes as req.file and there is no issue. From iPhone it comes as req.body.file. This was not the case earlier when I didn't have Nginx between and I'm guessing that it's somehow related to different sizes of images from iPhone and Android, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Or maybe this is the problem with multer?